# Unexpected } - Curly Braces around variable error

Tags: javascript, html, minify, pushstate

I'm having trouble passing data through a variable on Javascript. This requires {} around the variable to work. The code actually works on Chrome, but I get an error "Unexpected }" which interrupts minify. Brackets shows an error too.

This is the line:

```
    history.pushState({id}, null, id)
```

If I remove the {} leaving only id the error disappears, but the code no longer works.

This is a simple code to manipulate the address bar on a single page application (SPA). Without the {id} the back button doesn't work.

Here is the entire code:

```
 var boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));

 function selectBox(id) {
      boxes.forEach( function (b) {
           return b.classList.toggle('selected', b.id === id);
      });
 }

 boxes.forEach( function(b) {
     var id = b.id;
     b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          history.pushState({id}, null, id);
     });
 });
```

How can I fix this and without breaking the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the minfy would be happier with the equivalent: `{id:id}`

Comment: That's ES6 object shorthand, apparently minify doesn't understand it. Use the traditional syntax.

Comment: @MarkMeyer {id:id} might be equivalent but now it runs flawlessly without errors! Minify is working too! Thanks you so much! I hate these small syntax errors, made me lose an hour. :)

Comment: @tomDev glad it worked. Sounds like the minifier just isn't current with the latest javascript.